# Display only two records in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a requirement over here to display only two records on page load and when user clicks on show all button rest of the records should be displayed.

What I am currently doing is, on load bind just two records to the grid and when clicking on show all button destroying the grid and creating it again with all the records.

With this approach when I display number of records the user will get confused because initially the total records will be just 2 and when clicking on show all it will change according to the records.

To avoid this I am thinking to bind all the records in the first place and display only two records by some sort of kendo setting.

Is this possible?

I am using angularjs as well and will assign angular $scope object as data source to the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/local-data-binding"> 
    <title>Jayesh Goyani</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" /> 
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button value="show all" onclick="ShowAll()">Show All</button>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                    }
                },
                height: 550,
                groupable: true,
                dataBound: onDataBinding,
                sortable: true,
                columns: [{
                    field: "ContactTitle",
                    title: "Contact Title"
                }, {
                    field: "CompanyName",
                    title: "Company Name"
                }, {
                    field: "Country",
                    width: 150
                }]
            });
        }); 
        function onDataBinding(arg) {
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            $(grid.tbody).find("tr").hide();
            $(grid.tbody).find("tr:eq(0)").show();
            $(grid.tbody).find("tr:eq(1)").show();
        }
        function ShowAll() {
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            $(grid.tbody).find("tr").show();
        }
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.